# How can I surface this aggregate data on my Visualforce Page?

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql

I have Apex code that builds the data that I need from two SOQL queries. Records is the main query. This snippet helps build the extra data.

```
for(sObject a: Records){

   String algMilkQuery = 'SELECT count(ID) numberofchildren FROM Child_Consent_Form__c WHERE Allergies_Types__c INCLUDES (\'Dairy-free\') AND Child_Consent_Form__c.Active_Inactive__c = \'Active\' AND puLocation__r.Name = \''+ a.get('LocationName') + '\'';

   System.debug('****** SITE Name ********** ' + a.get('LocationName'));
   System.debug('****** SITE Notes ********** ' + a.get('LocationNotes'));
   System.debug('****** SITE Milk Location ********** ' + a.get('MilkLocation'));
   System.debug('****** SITE Location Type ********** ' + a.get('LocationType'));
   System.debug('****** SITE Number of Children with Allegries ********** ' + a.get('childrenwithalergies'));
   System.debug('****** SITE Number of Children ********** ' + a.get('numberofchildren'));

   sObject milkCount = Database.query(algMilkQuery);  

   if (milkCount != null) {
     System.debug('****** SITE Milk Count ********** ' + milkCount);
   } else {

     System.debug('****** SITE Milk Count ********** 0');
   }


   // Here is where I need to add it to a package and ship it off to the page.   

}
```

I am able to output the correct information in the log file. The problem I am having is understanding how I need to package the data to be used on my Visualforce Page. I am trying to get my head around sObjects, lists, and sets but am not sure which way to build this.

With the basic query result (`public List<sObject> Records {get; set;}`) I am able to populate the page without a problem.

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Records}" var="Record"> 
        <apex:column > 
            <apex:facet name="header">Site Name</apex:facet> 
            <apex:outputText value="{!Record['LocationName']}"/>
        </apex:column> 
        <apex:column > 
            <apex:facet name="header">Delievery Details</apex:facet>
            <apex:outputText value="{!Record['LocationNotes']}"/>
        </apex:column> 
        <apex:column > 
            <apex:facet name="header">Milk Location</apex:facet>
```

But as I mentioned, I need to add/combine additional elements that are outside of the first query so I can build the pageBlockTable. The logic works I just need an idea of how to package it for the `Visualforce Page`.

Answer (score 2):

Before I even begin to answer this question, a couple notes:

- Never use a dynamic query where a static one will do. You are more likely to introduce errors or even security vulnerabilities.

  Instead of:

  ```
  List<SObject> records = Database.query('SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ...');
  ```

  Use:

  ```
  List<SObject> records = [SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ...];
  ```
- Query on unique fields where possible. Specifically, query on the `Id` if you already have it.
- Never query in a loop if you can avoid it in any way.
- Concrete types are easier to work with than generics. You should almost never use a literal `List<SObject>` except when writing utilities. Instead use `List<Parent__c>`, `List<Child__c>`, `List<AggregateResult>` instead. Be as specific as possible.

---

If you only have one child collection to count, the simplest solution is to use a [`Left Outer Join`](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com#Left_Outer_Join). You actually get all the data in one query and no loops.

```
List<Parent__c> records = [
    SELECT
        Name, ParentField1__c, ParentField2__c,
        (
            SELECT ChildField1__c, ChildField2__c
            FROM Children__r WHERE ...
        )
    FROM Parent__c WHERE ...
];
```

Then in your markup, you don't need to use square bracket notation any more since you have a concrete type. And you can reference the size of the list directly:

```
<apex:column value="{!record.Name}" />
<apex:column value="{!record.NotesField__c}" />
<apex:column headerValue="Allergies" value="{!record.Children__r.size}" />
```

You can even filter on this child list using a [`Left Inner Join`](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com#Left_Inner_Join):

```
SELECT ... FROM Parent__c WHERE Id IN (
    SELECT LookupField__c FROM Child__c WHERE ...
)
```

---

If you want to apply multiple filters on the same child relationship, the solution gets muddier.

In a pure apex solution, you can apply a neat alias trick to get this data as a one-liner. But first, some context. With any `List<SObject>`, you can convert it to a `Map<Id, SObject>`, where the key corresponds to each record's `get(Id)` result. For instance:

```
Map<Id, Account> idToAccount = new Map<Id, Account>([SELECT Name FROM Account]);
```

With aggregate queries, you can *alias* a field to any value you please, including `Id`. So you can do:

```
SELECT LookupField__c Id, COUNT(Id) childCount FROM Child__c WHERE ...
```

And then that aggregate query will work inside this built-in map constructor:

```
Map<Id, AggregateResult> aggregates = new Map<Id, AggregateResult>([
    SELECT LookupField__c Id, COUNT(Id) childCount FROM Child__c WHERE ...
]);
```

Now in your markup, you could reference that map:

```
<apex:outputText value="{!aggregates[record.Id].get('childCount')}" />
```

---

*However*, the above solution will break if any of the aggregate values would be zero. That key will be missing from the map and throw an error. So you have to build your own map. Something like:

```
public with sharing class MyController
{
    public Map<Id, Integer> allergyCounts { get; private set; }
    public MyController()
    {
        records = [SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ...];
        allergyCounts = new Map<Id, Integer>();
        for (AggregateResult aggregate : [
            /*same query from above*/
        ]){
            allergyCounts.put(
                (Id)aggregate.get('Id'),
                (Integer)aggregate.get('childCount')
            );
        }
    }
    for (SObject record : records)
    {
        // here is where you cover the corner case
        // and ensure all keys exist in your map
        if (!allergyCounts.containsKey(record.Id))
        {
            allergyCounts.put(record.Id, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the information. Sadly I am more confused. Can I build a list with these collected variables and then go through and display them on my VF page?

Comment: Yes...You would just use property syntax (`{ get; private set; }`). You should really work your way through some Trailhead modules to familiarize yourself with the basics.